# Use multiples $this->loadModel('Model') or one using array?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using multiples `$this->loadModel('Model');` on my code, I wonder to performance (or other period) is better to use this way: `$this->loadModel(['Model', 'Model2']);`, Where should I put at the beginning of the method or above which will be used ?

```
public function edit($productId)
{
    $this->loadModel('Medias');
    //Code that uses the model

    $this->loadModel('Stores');
    $stores = $this->Stores->myStores($userId);

    $this->loadModel('Banners');
    //Code that uses the model
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Controller/ModelAwareTrait::loadModel()` doesn't take an array, so that matter resolved itself.

Not grouping the calls would only make sense/a difference if your code may conditionally return early before certain parts of your action. It should also be noted that you may be able to access the associated models via magic properties (like `$this->Stores->Banners`) in case they are associated.

If you wonder about performance, then I'd suggest that you have a look at the source and check what actually happens when invoking that method.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.5/src/Datasource/ModelAwareTrait.php#L88**

By default, the method basically wraps calls to `TableRegistry::get()`, and sets the return value to a dynamic property of the controller. Ultimately calls end up in [**`TableLocator::get()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.5/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php#L128), where some inflection, registry lookup, etc is going on, nothing that should significantly affect the performance.

If you want to know about the exact impact, then grab yourself a profiling tool (like for example [**Xdebug**](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler)), and measure it.